# What's the relation between quanutm hall effect and topological insulator state?

Tags: topological-insulators, quantum-hall-effect

In a recent PRX paper(https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.10.011050), I see that in 45nm and 50nm-thick Cd3As2 films, they find quantum hall effect and say that this is because of topological insulator surface state. Bulk Cd3As2 is 3D Dirac semimetal. I want to know the relation between quantum hall effect and topological insulator state. Thanks!